# @JsonView fails with 'IllegalStateException Can not override serializer' when using Spring repository

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

We're using some Spring (v4.1.3.RELEASE) repositories and lately started using @JsonView to filter some responses data with other Controllers we have in our system.
We've discovered today that jackson tries and fail to swap serializers for unknown reason of properties flagged with the @JsonView annotation.

Debugging led us to BeanSerializerBase.resolve(..) = lines #333-#337 where the assignment is made and fails later with the exception 'IllegalStateException Can not override serializer'. There is also a reference in the code to [JACKSON-364].

Removing all JsonView annotations fixed it as a workaround.

We're still trying to debug and nail the root cause of it but any hint will be appreciated here.

Thanks!

Comment: Also ran into the same problem. Had to remove JsonView annotations. Used Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE coming with Jackson 2.4.6 and spring-webmvc 4.1.7

Comment: Years later, updated libs (spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, jackson-databind 2.9.6), same issue. Simply patching the failing check like the answer below is not an option for me.
It works for me adding @JsonUnwrapped to the properties where i need a custom serializer, and adding the "wrap" in the custom serializer itself (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

We can see in source code

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter

```
    /**
     * Method called to assign value serializer for property
     * 
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public void assignSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> ser)
    {
        // may need to disable check in future?
        if (_serializer != null && _serializer != ser) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can not override serializer");
        }
        _serializer = ser;
    }
```

So we can't change serializer dynamicly with this writer class.

To hide this problem we can use (for example)

```
    public class ExtendBeanPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {

        // constructors

        @Override
        public BeanPropertyWriter unwrappingWriter(NameTransformer unwrapper) {
            return new ExtendUnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter(this, unwrapper);
        }

        @Override
        public void assignSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> ser) {
            _serializer = ser;
        }

    }
```

And we have to remember about UnwrappedBeanPropertyWriter

```
    public class ExtendUnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter extends UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter {


        // constructors

        @Override
        public void assignSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> ser) {
            _serializer = ser;
        }

    }
```

Then we can extend BeanSerializerModifier, method - changeProperties, to change writer's classes to our implementations and avoid this exception.

```
public class ExtendBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    private AnnotationIntrospector annotationIntrospector;

    // constructors

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        annotationIntrospector = null == config ? null : config.getAnnotationIntrospector();
        List<BeanPropertyWriter> result = new ArrayList<BeanPropertyWriter>();
        for (BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriter : beanProperties) {
            BeanPropertyWriter bpw = beanPropertyWriter;
            // we can get views from bpw.getViews(); active view from config.getActiveView();
            // we also can use own annotations, for example - beanDesc.getBeanClass().getAnnotation(SomeClass.class);
            result.add(getExtendBPW(bpw));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public BeanPropertyWriter getExtendBPW(BeanPropertyWriter bpw) {
        BeanPropertyWriter writer = new ExtendBeanPropertyWriter(bpw);
        if (null != annotationIntrospector) {
            NameTransformer unwrapper = annotationIntrospector.findUnwrappingNameTransformer(bpw.getMember());
            if (null != unwrapper) {
                writer = writer.unwrappingWriter(unwrapper);
            }
        }
        return writer;
    }

}
```

And even after that you can get a problems with JsonView.
You also maybe have to add your own HttpMessageConverter and/or method Interceptor (you can find examples in internet).

Comment: Seems very descriptive! :)
I'll try to test and feedback as soon as i'll get back to it.
Thanks!

Comment: Edited. I used this approach in an enterprise project, where I participate, and it's works more than 8 months in production without problems.